# Rendering a Voxelized Mesh

Tags: 3d, rendering, voxels

I've been reading many papers about how to voxelize meshes using different GPU techniques, but I've ran into a problem that I'm not sure how to solve properly.  I understand the process of how to convert a 3D mesh into voxels stored in a 3D texture, but I don't know a very efficient way to display the voxelized mesh after this.  Many of the papers I have read gloss over this part.

The one way I can think of accomplishing this is to draw an instanced cube, one for each voxel.  Each instanced cube would have texture coordinates that correspond to it's location in the 3D texture.  Every instanced cube would also go through a geometry shader.  If the texture's entry at the current coordinates was 0 (empty voxel), then the geometry shader simply wouldn't output any triangles.

Is this an efficient method/good idea?

Comment: Polling about a solution for your project, or for alternate solutions, is essentially a question of opinion.  SE questions ought to have correct answers, and polls do not.  See the help about what type of question should be avoided: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask  Your best option is to attempt your solution and observe the results.  If you notice a specific problem with those results and need help resolving it, come back and post _that_ question.

Comment: Yeah, that's a fair point.  I just figured since every paper I've read glosses over it, there must be a "standardized" or "correct" way of rendering voxels efficiently.  In hindsight, I guess this isn't the case.

Comment: @BryanWallin What are the alternatives to using cubes to represent the voxels? That is the only way I thought of. It sounds like the naive standard way to do this.

Comment: There is another technique called [Marching Cubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes) that generates mesh data based on 3D textures instead of simple cubes.  My question wasn't about using non-cube shapes, but more about how to efficiently render cubes in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a selection of display methods for voxel data.

The most easy to grasp is certainly, one voxel=1 box, but it will leave you with a very cubic looking world.

You can also look into marching cubes (going through your grid and testing how full each set of 8 voxels is, and filling with a selection of pre-generated meshes). There are a number of related meshing techniques that will produce other smooth results.

If you want to get really fancy, you could build a shader that works as a ray-caster - trace a line from the camera to each screen pixel until you hit a voxel, and then render.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I should mention that I plan to use the voxel structure as a foundation for realtime global illumination (https://research.nvidia.com/publication/interactive-indirect-illumination-using-voxel-cone-tracing), and so I only need to view the voxels as a debugging method.  I just didn't want the process of viewing voxels to be incredibly slow.